# Choosing Indices Databases

Tags: sql, database, indexing, db2

I am having some issues choosing the best indices for this problem. Given a set of queries:

-- Query 1

```
select CUSTOMERS.PID
from CUSTOMERS join
     PARTICIP
     on CUSTOMERS.PID = PARTICIP.PID
group by CUSTOMERS.PID
having COUNT(CUSTOMERS.PID) = 1;
```

-- Query 2

```
select CUSTOMERS.PID
from CUSTOMERS join
     PARTICIP
     on CUSTOMERS.PID = PARTICIP.PID
group by CUSTOMERS.PID
having COUNT(CUSTOMERS.PID) >= 2;
```

-- Query 3

```
select hasa.pid,strno as "Street #", street, city, prov as Province
from ((addresses join hasa on hasa.addrid = addresses.addrid) join 
      customers
      on customers.pid = hasa.pid
     )
order by city;
```

-- Query 4

```
select * 
from guides 
where pid in (select pid 
              from particip 
              where tid in (select unique tid 
                            from itineraries 
                            where date >= '2015-01-01' and date <= '2015-12-31'));
```

-- Query 5

```
select age, gender 
from persons 
where persons.pid in (select hase.pid 
                      from hase 
                      where hase.pid in (select * from employees));
```

-- Query 6

```
select provid 
from isp 
where provid NOT in (select provid as service 
                     from isp 
                     group by provid, svctype 
                     having svctype = 'ACCOM');
```

-- Query 7

```
select provid 
from isp 
where provid in (select provid 
                 from isp 
                 where ((svctype != 'ACCOM' and svctype = 'MEAL') 
                        or (svctype = 'ACCOM' and svctype != 'MEAL')) 
                 group by provid 
                 having count(unique svctype) = 1);
```

-- Query 8

```
select unique provid, svctype 
from isp 
where penalty = 100 or penalty = 200;
```

-- Query 9

```
select pid, sum(amount) as "totalSalary", count(pid) as "numTours" 
from hasco 
group by pid 
order by sum(amount) desc;
```

-- Query 10

```
select distinct hasco.TID 
from hasco 
join (select * 
      from tours 
      where status = 'I' OR status = 'F') as table1 on hasco.tid = table1.tid  
where amount >= 5000;
terminate;
```

and the ER diagram:
[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lq2b.png)

I am tasked to choose two attributes to index that will provide the most benefit. No mentions have been made about any quantities of queries or modifications to the table. Thanks.

EDIT: I simply need one or two attributes to index and some reasoning behind it to help understand.

Also, is it generally better to have non-clustered over clustered? Thanks.

Comment: I started, but you should try formatting the question so it can be read.

Comment: Trying to do that now, sorry new to this.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping format it!

Answer (score 0):

Given the above queries and ER diagram alone it is not possible to pick "the best" or anything with "the most" benefit. You (and the optimizer) also need to know about the data ("statistics"). How many rows are involved, how are values distributed, and many more questions.

If you only have small tables, the optimizer might pick a tablescan and no indexes are needed at all. In general, try to figure out whether indexes on the predicate columns and join columns help.

Have you already used the db2 explain facility or the [design/index advisor (db2advis)](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002452.html) to look into this?

Comment: No I have not, in the case there is not a "best" solution any solution would be fine. I am thinking of indexing isp.svctype since it is being used in the where clause of a few queries. I am stuck on deciding whether to have the index be clustered or non clustered. I am assuming that db2 automatically indexes primary keys by clustered manner. Is this true?

Comment: Very useful tool though, I will try to see what it says, thanks!